# Is there a better solution rather than changing wp-content folder persmission to 777 to prevent asking me to put ftp parameters?

Tags: wordpress, ftp

I have a running wordpress website and the only issue I have is that each time I want to save an update it's asking me to enter my ftp password.

[image]

Is there a better solution to remove this popup without changing `wp-content` folder permission to 777?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have run into this issue when the files on my web server are configured with the wrong owner or group.

From the WordPress codex:

> Typically, all files should be owned by your user (ftp) account on your web server, and should be writable by that account. On shared hosts, files should never be owned by the webserver process itself (sometimes this is www, or apache, or nobody user).

https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

This is something that you will need to resolve on your web server if you know your user and group. Your username is likely the same as your FTP user.

```
chown -R user:group /path/to/wordpress
```

If you are on a shared hosting environment you will need to contact your host so that they can fix this problem.

You should also avoid using 777 permissions on your folders. Folders should be 755.